# bootstrap css interfering with google maps infowindow v3

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps-api-3

I have a simple infowindow to a marker on my map,

I want the default infowindow design, instead I get ugly infowindow, it seems like its interfering with bootstrap.

here is the link to the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GTrr6/2/

```
var los_angeles = new google.maps.LatLng(34.0695831, -118.2634431);
var myOptions = {zoom: 14, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, center: los_angeles};
var map = new google.maps.Map($("#map-canvas")[0], myOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: los_angeles, map: map, title: "your location");

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: '<div class="iw">test info</div>'});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () { infoWindow.open(map, marker); });
```

if you click on the marker it will display a infowindow, but it looks a little different than the default info window on google map.

Answer (score 0):

Try to supress the rule "img { max-width: 100%; }" in bootstrap css. It cause problems with googlemap.
If the rule don't exist, then i don't know.

Comment: how do I suppress the css rule? should I host the bootstrap css file myself and not depend on cdns?

Comment: Cleaner way is to add your own css style sheet and add a rule :
`img {
    max-width: none;
}` as also suggest @JakeSidSmith

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra parenthesis as shown in the console:
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )"

Remove the last one from the following line. Should look like this. :)

```
var map = new google.maps.Map($("#map-canvas")[0], myOptions);
```

This thread has a fix: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/2410

```
#map-id img {
    max-width: none;
}
```

Comment: it still doesn't work for me.. http://jsfiddle.net/GTrr6/1/
I updated the jsfiddle and inserted that css